# C++: Issue in loading xml in variant using _RecordsetPTr rs->Fields->GetItem("ABC")->GetValue();

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008-r2, recordset

I have to read data from recordset for one coloumn whose datatype is text. Below mentioned is the syntax:

```
VARIANT vProps = rs->Fields->GetItem("Props")->GetValue();
```

Here, "Props" is the name of the column which contains the xml data in text datatype. When I tried to get the value in vProps it returns some invalid value and data is not populated in variant.

I have saved the content of the column field in a .xml file and file loaded properly. Please note the size of the file is 74kb.

Likewise there are other entries also in database table for "Props" column, however in case when size is less than 10 KB, variant populated successfully using the same piece of code.

Is there any limitation to VARIANT datatypes  size ?
How to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has defined [limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) on the maximum sizes and numbers of various objects defined in SQL Server components.

For example,

> Bytes per short string column: 8,000